# После прохождения всех тестов с использованием jest не появляется приглашение командной строки

Tags: юнит-тесты, тестирование, testng, jest

Вот что я экспортирую в файл тестов (а так же в точку входа):

```
// app.ts

// много импортов

class App {

    public readonly app: Express = express();

    constructor() {
        this.app.use(/*всякие стандартные мидлвары*/);
        this.app.use('/api/user', userApi); // и прочие роуты
    }
}

const server = new Server( new App().app );
export default server;
```

Вот как выглядит файл с тестами:

```
import request = require('supertest');
import app from '../../../lib/app';

describe('User login test', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        app.close();
    });

    test('Send invalid token', async (done) => {
        const res = await request(app)
            .post('/api/user/v3/login')
            .send({data: 'woBxaXd1cS0tLVVxMTU0NDUyMjA0ODA4Mw=='})
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        expect(res.status).toBe(403);
        done();
    });

    // ну и аналогичные, ожидающие другие статус-коды
});
```

Запускаю тесты следующей командой:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --detectOpenHandles"
}
```

Так же использую jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

После запуска тестов выдается следующее сообщение:

```
PASS  test/user/v2/user-login-routes-v2.test.ts (0.273s)
  User login test
    √ Login new user (204ms)
    √ Send existing token (23ms)
    √ Send invalid token (30ms)
    √ Send empty token (16ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        30.452s, estimated 46s
Ran all test suites.
```

И все, больше никаких сообщений в консоль не падает. Но и приглашение не появляется - останавливаю процесс через ctrl+C.
Если запускать без флага --detectOpenHandles, то после прохождения тестов появляется сообщение:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Но с флагом ничего не показывает (когда я не использовал колбэк done например, сообщения появлялись).

Как мне завершить процесс после прохождения тестов?

Comment: Могу предположить что экземпляр `Express`, который вы запускаете продолжает работать после завершения теста, не смотря на конструкцию `app.close()`, в методе `afterAll`.

Comment: @SergeyEgorov похоже на то, надо поверить, спасибо)

Comment: Запуск тестируемых бэкендов я обычно не включаю в код тестов совсем. Старт навешиваю на команду `npm start`, а остановку на команду `npm stop`.  А чтобы это можно было сделать одной командой, заставив к примеру после ввода в консоли `npm test` выполнить запуск бэкенда, прогнать тесты и остановить бэкенд затем, можно воспользоваться пакетом `pm2`. У него есть и программный интерфейс тоже. То есть любые подробности сценариев запуска и остановки можно написать на том же `JavaScript`.

Comment: @SergeyEgorov хорошая идея